# Music player locking up with large number of songs on sd card

Tags: 8.0, music, xbox-music

I have a Lumia 520 with my >11k music library synced onto an SD card.  I can play individual songs/albums without problem; but when I try to shuffle and play my entire collection in xbox music player a single song starts to play and the UI immediately freezes hard:  It never refreshes to show what song is playing; no buttons either soft, or physical (eg volume) work; and when the song ends the phone remains completely non-responsive until I remove the battery.

With the SD card removed and a small number of songs on the phones internal flash the shuffle option works as expected; but one of the main reasons I bought this phone was that I wanted to be able to carry all my music with me and shuffle through the entire collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent XBox Music update/WP8.1 developer OS update (I think this one is equivalent to the 8.1 release going out to the general public), has fixed both the problem in 8.0, and the new problem (very long delays on the next/previous buttons with huge play lists) in the initial 8.1 developer preview build from a few months ago.  It now loads almost immediately and can switch between songs with only a second or two of delay.